# Hosting a small business website on Heroku Hobby?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, deployment, web-deployment

I'm looking for a hosting solution for my transportation booking website built with React JS, Material-Ui, Node JS, Express and small MySQL database. The actual booking process is handled by LimoAnywhere plug-in that opens within the app. Being familiar with Heroku is it a good option to get a $7 Hobby plan with 24/7 dino working? I'm not expecting much traffic, maybe 500-1000 hits per month.
Should I look for a VPS hosting like Bluehost, DigitalOcean, Linode, AfterBurst etc?

Answer (score 0):

you should compare both Heroku and Digital Ocean. As of now I can see the Digital Ocean is giving more value to money ratio.

Comment: My problem is that a have no experience in Digital Ocean deployment while I have hosted projects on Heroku. Would it make any difference in a website that has low traffic?

Comment: Nope, go with the one you are familiar with, later you can migrate (if architected decently)